# Integrate SFMC with Firebase to send Push Notifications

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, sdk

Our App development team has a mobile app in Xamarin which does not support the SFMC SDK for Mobile Push. So, now they want to introduce firebase layer so that SFMC can send the notification to firebase and app team can pull the same from firebase and trigger the notifications to actual consumer device.

So, is there any feature available in SFMC to connect with firebase. Also, is it possible to send push notifications from SFMC when the app has been developed without the sdk.

Answer (score 0):

SFMC uses Google's and Apple's push messaging services to deliver all messages.  What you would need to do is get the individuals device registered with the Marketing Cloud servers.  Please contact your Salesforce support representative as the routes to accomplish this are not publicly documented.